# Minimization: taking advantage of asymmetry in computation time for each parameter

Tags: python, scipy, minimization, scipy-optimize

I have a (relatively standard) minimization problem, where I have a set of experimental data (xdata, ydata), a model y=f(x, parameters), and I want to extract the parameters. [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) would be my go-to, but there is a trick in the structure of the function to minimize. It is actually a two step calculation where some parameters are involved in a much quicker calculation than others.

Example code with mockup functions and data follows (in the real thing, `param_a` and `param_b` include multiple parameters, if it matters). Here the structure of the model is not used at all:

```
'''Runs, but not optimal.'''
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
from time import sleep

def quick(array_in, param):
    return param * array_in

def slow(array_in, param):
    sleep(0.1)
    return np.exp(param*array_in)

def model(x, param_a, param_b):
    intermediary = slow(x, param_a)
    return quick(intermediary, param_b)

p_actual = [0.5, 2.0]
xdata = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0)
ydata = model(xdata, *p_actual) + np.random.randn(*xdata.shape)

# The following is inefficient because parameter asymmetry is hidden to curve_fit
# Change the 0.1s sleep time in slow() to experiment
popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p0=np.asarray([1.0, 1.0]))
print(popt)  # about [0.5, 2.0]
```

I would imagine the minimization algorithm could take advantage of the structure of the problem where changing `param_b` is really easy (if a previous call to model with the same `param_a` was made). In the real case, `slow` involves solving ODEs and takes several minutes, while `quick` is a weighted sum of numpy arrays which takes (at least) four orders of magnitude less time.

The following is an implementation of this idea, including a test comparing the two methods for a non-trivial fitting problem. It turns out that in ~50% of cases the "improved" version calls slow() `*more*` times (sometimes to converge to a better fit, but sometimes not); that might be due to the interaction of scipy.optimize routines and the energy landscape of the problem. I suspect a working solution requires more thinking about the math than I put in.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from inspect import getfullargspec
import scipy.optimize
import random
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _number_of_arguments(f):
    '''
    f must be a function taking a fixed number >= 1 of non-keyword arguments, because that's what scipy.optimize.curve_fit operates on. If so, the number of those arguments is returned. Otherwise, an error is thrown.
    '''
    fas = getfullargspec(f)
    if fas.varargs is not None:
        raise ValueError('Function accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments.', f)
    if fas.varkw is not None or fas.kwonlyargs:
        raise ValueError('Function accepts keyword arguments.', f)
    n = len(fas.args)
    if n == 0:
        raise ValueError('Function takes no arguments, it should take at least one (x).')
    return n

def _score(ydata, yest, sigma=None):
    sigma = sigma if sigma is not None else np.ones(yest.shape)
    return np.sum(((yest - ydata)/sigma)**2)

def _optimize_std(fslow, fquick, xdata, ydata, ps_guess=None, pq_guess=None, sigma=None):

    Nps = _number_of_arguments(fslow) - 1
    Npq = _number_of_arguments(fquick) - 1
    assert ps_guess is None or Nps == len(ps_guess)
    assert pq_guess is None or Npq == len(pq_guess)

    assert xdata.shape == ydata.shape
    assert sigma is None or sigma.shape == ydata.shape

    def f(x, *p):
        assert len(p) == Nps + Npq
        return fquick( fslow(x, *p[:Nps]), *p[Nps:])

    ps_guess = np.array(ps_guess) if ps_guess is not None else np.ones(Nps)
    pq_guess = np.array(pq_guess) if pq_guess is not None else np.ones(Npq)
    p_guess = np.concatenate((ps_guess, pq_guess))
    p_opt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=p_guess, sigma=sigma)

    return p_opt[:Nps], p_opt[Nps:]

def optimize(fslow, fquick, xdata, ydata, ps_guess=None, pq_guess=None, sigma=None):
    '''Two-step curve fitting for two-part function.

    Two functions `fquick: interm, *pq -> y` and `fslow: x, *ps -> interm`
    define together `f: x, *ps, *pq -> y = fquick( fslow(x, *pq), *ps)`.
    Assuming that `f: xdata -> ydata` one can fit the ps, pq parameters; we
    return ps0, pq0 such that f(xdata, ps0, pq0) ~ ydata.

    This whole function should have an output equivalent to that of the
    standard scipy.optimize.curve_fit. However, internally, it is written so
    that the fewest possibles calls to fslow() are made (at the expense of more
    calls to fquick). That is possible because the intermediary calculation
    `interm = fslow(x, *ps)` can be reused for multiple calls to `y =
    fquick(interm, *pq)`. If the latter is really quick, it can make sense to
    fully optimize the `fquick` part at each step of the optimization for
    `fslow`; this increases greatly the number of calls to `fquick`, but the
    optimization that is actually costly in function calls is madek with fewer
    parameters.

    The first argument of fslow() and the output of fquick() must be 1d arrays
    with consistent size. The output of fslow() must be consumed as the first
    argument of fquick(), but can be any kind of object.

    Args:
        fslow (callable): function with two arguments.
            fslow: interm, *ps -> y
        fquick (callable): function with two arguments.
            fquick: x, *pq -> interm
        xdata (np.array): evaluation points.
        ydata (np.array): values to fit.

    Returns: : optimal parameters for fslow : optimal parameters for fquick
    '''

    assert xdata.shape == ydata.shape
    assert sigma is None or sigma.shape == ydata.shape

    Nps = _number_of_arguments(fslow) - 1
    Npq = _number_of_arguments(fquick) - 1
    assert ps_guess is None or Nps == len(ps_guess)
    assert pq_guess is None or Npq == len(pq_guess)

    cur_ps = np.array(ps_guess, copy=True) if ps_guess is not None else np.ones(Nps)
    cur_pq = np.array(pq_guess, copy=True) if pq_guess is not None else np.ones(Npq)

    def f_with_quickopt(x, *ps, sigma=None):
        '''
        That function keeps the state of pq between calls via the pq attribute.
        That attribute must hence be set before the first call to the function.
        For more details on the method, see
        https://python-forum.io/Thread-function-state-between-calls?pid=38969#pid38969
        '''
        try:
            f_with_quickopt.pq
        except AttributeError as exc:
            raise RuntimeError('You must define attribute pq.') from exc

        interm = fslow(x, *ps)

        def f_quick_score_to_minimize(pq):
            yest = fquick(interm, *pq)  # pq not long enough?
            return _score(ydata, yest, sigma=sigma)

        solve_quick = scipy.optimize.minimize(
            f_quick_score_to_minimize, f_with_quickopt.pq
            )

        f_with_quickopt.pq = solve_quick.x

        return fquick(interm, *f_with_quickopt.pq)

    f_with_quickopt.pq = cur_pq
    # Main optimization call - here's what should take most time
    ps_opt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f_with_quickopt, xdata, ydata, p0=cur_ps, sigma=sigma)

    pq_opt = f_with_quickopt.pq


    return ps_opt, pq_opt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def slow(x, a, b):
        slow.Ncalls += 1
        sleep(0.01)
        return a*x**2 + b * x

    def quick(x, a, b):
        quick.Ncalls += 1
        return a*x + b*np.cos(x)

    slow.Ncalls = 0
    quick.Ncalls = 0

    def model(x, ps, pq):
        return quick(slow(x, *ps), *pq)

    ps_actual = 1.0 + np.random.random((2, ))
    pq_actual = 1.0 + np.random.random((2, ))

    xdata = np.linspace(-0.0, 2.0, num=1000)
    y_theory = model(xdata, ps_actual, pq_actual)
    ydata = y_theory + np.random.randn(*xdata.shape)/5

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'k.', label='data')
    plt.plot(xdata, y_theory, 'r-', label='actual')
    for (lab, opti) in [
        ('std: {q} quick(), {s} slow()', _optimize_std),
        ('asym: {q} quick(), {s} slow()', optimize)
        ]:
        slow.Ncalls = 0
        quick.Ncalls = 0

        ps, pq = opti(slow, quick, xdata, ydata)

        leg = lab.format(q=quick.Ncalls, s=slow.Ncalls)
        yplot = model(xdata, ps, pq)
        plt.plot(xdata, yplot, label=leg)

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the value from the previous `pq` minimization (which might have used a very different `ps`) the best guess you have?

Comment: It is "best" in terms of staying close to the naive algorithm (where your best guess for `pq` at the start of step N+1 is its value at the end of step N because you're operating on both `pq` and `ps` at the same time). I assume it is also "best" in terms of (1) starting in the attraction basin of the same local minimum and (2) starting closer to that local minimum, but I do not think there is a way to know for sure without information about the function to minimize.

Comment: The direct approach lets the optimization driver choose the next `ps` and `pq` together, and it will generally change each at every step.  (That doesn’t necessarily make it better, just inequivalent.)